# Geometric sequence with second term $12$, sum $50$, and common ratio greater than $0.5$

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

> The second term of a geometric sequence is $12$ and the sum to infinity of the corresponding series is $50$. Find the first term and the common ratio, which is greater than $0.5$.

Answer: $a = 20, r = 0.6$.
I know that the first term is $12/r$. I tried plugging it into the formula for sum to infinity, but I'm not getting the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should be more careful in calculating next time?

We have
$$a=\frac{12}r$$
$$\frac a{1-r}=50$$
Thus
$$\frac{12/r}{1-r}=50$$
$$\frac{12}{1-r}=50r$$
$$12=50r(1-r)=50r-50r^2$$
$$50r^2-50r+12=0$$
Solving, we get $r=\frac25$ or $r=\frac35$, and take the latter due to the condition $r>\frac12$. Thus the first term is $\frac{12}r=20$.

Answer (score 1):

let me use the usual notation for [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). Then we have $ar=12$ and as this is a convergent series (otherwise you wouldn't have a real number for the infinite sum) $$\dfrac{a}{1-r}=50.$$ Now solve these two equations for $a$ and $r.$